# Print prime numbers till N in C++

Tags: c++

Kindly point out what is wrong in my code. It is a code to print prime no. till a particular number n.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,c=0;
    cin>>n;
    for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
      for (j=2; j<i; j++)
      {
          if (i%j==0)
          c++;
      }  
      if (c==0)
      cout <<i <<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flag `c` maintained for  prime number printing has to be reset on every `iteration`.

Comment: See also [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for efficient prime number generation.

Answer (score 6):

In order to fix the code to show all primes, just add one line (commented):

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,j,c=0;
    cin>>n;
    for (i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
      // add this line
      c = 0;
      for (j=2; j<i; j++)
      {
          if (i%j==0)
          c++;
      }  
      if (c==0)
      cout <<i <<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However you might need some other fixes for better performance. For example, consider adding `c` condition in the second loop:

```
for (j=2; !c && j<i; j++)
```

Comment: if you notice `2` is considered as non-prime number. you can start inner loop from `j=3`

Comment: Also the upper bound of inner loop could be `sqrt(i)+1` instead of `i` for better performance

Comment: right, if you want to avoid float numbers you just put `j * j <= i` or similar, also if you have some memory, you can just go by primes, but the last approach is probably off-topic

Comment: Eh, when I was a kid, mom told me that I should declare variables as close to usage location as possible...